# docker-compose volumes not works

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have this docker-compose.yml

```
  client:
    build:
      context:  ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443" 
    volumes:
       - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

Also I have nginx.conf that is supposed to be proxy to client. Everything is good. Also I've set up ssl on host nginx - that is working as expected.

Now I want to use ssl in client-prox-nginx - it's inside docker.
I've copied nginx generated from certbot to docker nginx and it is not working.

So - with same nginx setup as host, docker nginx is not encrypting with ssl. I suspect that it is because docker can't access letsencrypt folder. Are "volumes" in docker-compose correct? How can I test that?

I know that nginx.conf is correct - it is copy of nginx.conf from host that is working perfectly.

Simply put - docker can't access localhost files. I used volumes and it not working.

Comment: Did you connect to the container to see if the volume works?

Comment: That's the part of the question. How can I do that?

Comment: You could try to docker exec inside the container... full command being docker exec -ti <containerID> /bin/bash or sh at the end...

Comment: This question is very confusing

Comment: I've updated the question George

Answer (score 0):

So per night-gold comment, I've connected to container. Files (ssl certs) are accessible from there. 
But still ssl is not working. I will post another question. Hosts are working as expected, I'm layman in docker.